# Scroll down a client view area in MFC automatically

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++

Requirement :
In a view , results of a task will be displayed . When the task results exceed view area the scroll bar has to scroll down automatically pointing to last displayed result.
Currently it is displaying to starting point.

Need VC++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used get Scroll range , max pos and the setpos to max position